# Bootstrap 3 radio button are stacked horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my Bootstrap 3 radio buttons to appear inline, not horizontally stacked. I followed:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/radio/

To get:

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showProgramTableForm">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
                        <button type="button" id="addProgramBtn" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Add Program</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">   
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rbProgramAll" name="rbProgramAll">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="rbProgramAll">All programs</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Material inline 2 -->
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rbProgramGroup" name="rbProgramGroup">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="rbProgramGroup">My Group's programs</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Material inline 3 -->
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rbProgramMine" name="rbProgramMine">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="rbProgramMine">My programs</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /container -->
        </form>
```

These are stacked horizontally.

Comment: the div's you place form-check-inline will inline the elements in that div. see the example below to see how to correctly follow the bootstrap doc's

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
    <input type="radio" id="rbProgramAll" name="rbProgram">
    <label class="radio-inline" for="rbProgramAll">All programs</label>
                     
    <input type="radio" id="rbProgramGroup" name="rbProgram">
    <label class="radio-inline" for="rbProgramGroup">My Group's programs</label>
                     
    <input type="radio" id="rbProgramMine" name="rbProgram">
    <label class="radio-inline" for="rbProgramMine">My programs</label>
</div>
```